# XTB api The client and server cannot communicate

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I am trying demo xtb api code.
But I am getting this error.

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090331): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

Obviously I google it and found that adding this line should help.

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But it does not help.
Its really just demo code from their app and I tried it in clean .net console app.
http://developers.xstore.pro/api/tutorials/first_steps_dotnet2

What I am doing wrong?
This is demo code if somebody is interrested. (yes changing credentials to correct one does not help.)

```
using System.Net;
using xAPI.Commands;
using xAPI.Records;
using xAPI.Responses;
using xAPI.Sync;

Server serverData = Servers.DEMO;
long userId = 12345;
string password = "pass";
string appName = "firstApp";
// should be left blank
// to get more info about appId and appName visit http://developers.xstore.pro/api/tutorials/appid_and_appname
string appId = "";
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server address: " + serverData.Address + " port: " + serverData.MainPort + " streaming port: " + serverData.StreamingPort);
    // Connect to server
    SyncAPIConnector connector = new SyncAPIConnector(serverData);
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to the server");
    // Login to server
    Credentials credentials = new Credentials(userId, password, appId, appName);
    LoginResponse loginResponse = APICommandFactory.ExecuteLoginCommand(connector, credentials, true);
    Console.WriteLine("Logged in as: " + userId);
    // Execute GetServerTime command
    ServerTimeResponse serverTimeResponse = APICommandFactory.ExecuteServerTimeCommand(connector, true);
    Console.WriteLine("Server time: " + serverTimeResponse.TimeString);
    // Execute GetAllSymbols command
    AllSymbolsResponse allSymbolsResponse = APICommandFactory.ExecuteAllSymbolsCommand(connector, true);
    Console.WriteLine("All symbols count: " + allSymbolsResponse.SymbolRecords.Count);
    // Print first 5 symbols
    Console.WriteLine("First five symbols:");
    foreach (SymbolRecord symbolRecord in allSymbolsResponse.SymbolRecords.Take(5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" > " + symbolRecord.Symbol + " ask: " + symbolRecord.Ask + " bid: " + symbolRecord.Bid);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An exception occured: " + ex.ToString());
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Is your Windows up-to-date?

Comment: @SalmanA no its company PC. Like one year old windows mostly. I will try on updated one today.

Comment: The code sample worked out of the box for me. I a guessing the PC having issues has some protocol or cipher suites not installed/disabled.  I would suggest using a software called "IIS Crypto" to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Great I will have my personal PC today so I can try it. Thank you very much for trying. Please post it as answer so I can close question and reward bounty.

Comment: `adding this line should help.` no it won't, it will prevent your application from using newer algorithms. In all *supported* .NET versions (ie 4.6.2) the best option available by Windows is used. And in all *supported* Windows versions, TLS 1.2 is available. In older (and by now unsupported) versions you have to patch the OS to enable TLS 1.2

Comment: What is XTB and what does `xstore.pro` have to do with it?  What *financial* site fails to use HTTPS even for documentation pages and worse, uses the *wrong* domain name in their certificate? Legitimate financial services use the strictest algorithms with the longest keys, not wildcard certificates (*.xtb.com) on totally unrelated sites (developers.xstore.pro).

Comment: It worked on different PC.